# logging syslog-ng logs Windows logs in multiple lines

Tags: windows, logging, syslog-ng

I have a problem with logging my Windows server by syslog-ng Agent for Windows v5.0.7 to my Main Syslog server with installed Syslog-ng PE v5.0.

Logs from the agent walks in a multiline shape, see below.
 Has anyone had a similar problem? Is there a configuration option, so that the logs went in one line? Or some rewrite configuration?

I thank you all

Configuration for Windows logs in syslog.conf at syslog server and multiple log:

```
filter f_syslog_win_exc { host("(11.22.33.44)"); };
destination d_syslog_win_exc { file("/var/nsm/windows_syslog/test/exch/$HOST-$R_YEAR$R_MONTH$R_DAY.log"); };
log { source(remote_windows); filter(f_syslog_win_exc);       destination(d_syslog_win_exc); };



Jun  9 14:51:33 11.22.33.44 1084 <133>1 2015-06-09T14:51:33+02:00 win_server_2k8 Microsoft_Windows_security_auditing. 508 - [win@18372.4 EVENT_CATEGORY="User Account Management" EVENT_FACILITY="16" EVENT_ID="4725" EVENT_LEVEL="0" EVENT_NAME="Security" EVENT_REC_NUM="210139" EVENT_SID="N/A" EVENT_SOURCE="Microsoft Windows security auditing." EVENT_TASK="User Account Management" EVENT_TYPE="Success Audit" EVENT_USERNAME="win_server_2k8\\syslog-user"][meta sequenceId="3" sysUpTime="14899"] 

Jun  9 14:51:33      4725    Security        win_server_2k8\syslog-user   User    Success Audit   win_server_2k8   User Account Management          A user account was disabled.

Jun  9 14:51:33 11.22.33.44 Subject:

Jun  9 14:51:33 11.22.33.44 Security ID:  win_server_2k8\test

Jun  9 14:51:33 11.22.33.44 Account Name:  test

Jun  9 14:51:33 11.22.33.44 Account Domain:  win_server_2k8       210139  A user account was disabled.

Jun  9 14:51:33 11.22.33.44 Subject:

Jun  9 14:51:33 11.22.33.44 Security ID:  win_server_2k8\test

Jun  9 14:51:33 11.22.33.44 Account Name:  test
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the syslog-ng Windows Agent sends logs using the new, RFC5424 protocol. The receiving side seems to use the legacy syslog protocol. You should use a syslog() source instead of tcp() on the receiving side, and that takes proper care of multi-line messages.

Comment: thanks, but I tried to use 

syslog(ip(0.0.0.0) port(5144) transport("tcp") flags(syslog-protocol));
syslog(ip(0.0.0.0) port(5144) transport("udp") flags(syslog-protocol));

in my syslog.conf
and didn't wokr for me - its still multiline